# Pass asp.net ClientId to Javascript Function - inline as a param

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have a asp Image Button that needs to be clicked via a Javascript function.
The keypress of a textbox should fire this image buttons server side event as well upon hitting the enter key.
The code is as follows: -

Markup

```
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/butt_searchoff.png"
    class="sb_search" ToolTip="Search the Database" AlternateText="Search" OnClick="ImageButton3_Click" OnClientClick="SetExpandedCount()"/>

    <input id="tbSearch" runat="server" class="sb_input" type="text" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return OverridePostBackOnEnter(event, '" & ImageButton3.ClientID & "');" />
```

I want to pass the ImageButton3 ClientId as a param to a Javascript function called OverridePostBackOnEnter.

The Javascript looks like this:

```
     function OverridePostBackOnEnter(event, ctrl) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            alert(ctrl);
            if ($.browser.mozilla) {
                __doPostBack(ctrl, 'OnClick'); //for IE
            }
            else {
                //but for other browsers you should use
                __doPostBack(ctrl, 'OnClick');
            }
        }
    };
```

What I'm finding is a) I can't get the correct ClientId to be passed, I just get either undefined or null.

and b) if I hard code and change the ctrl to 'cmain_ctl00_ImageButton3' the __dopostback is not invoking my server-side code for the ImageButton3.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Ok think I have found a solution for this and thought I should update the post in case anyone needs it.

Firstly I have set the 'ClientIdMode' on ImageButton3 to 'Static'

```
     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/butt_searchoff.png" class="sb_search" ToolTip="Search the Database" AlternateText="Search" OnClick="ImageButton3_Click" OnClientClick="SetExpandedCount()"/>
```

this allows me to pass the id of the button to the function 'OverridePostBackOnEnter'

```
    <input id="tbSearch" runat="server" class="sb_input" type="text" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return OverridePostBackOnEnter(event, 'ImageButton3');" />
```

Then my Javascript becomes:

```
    function OverridePostBackOnEnter(event, ctrl) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            if ($.browser.mozilla) {
                var overridctrl = document.getElementById(ctrl);
                __doPostBack(overridctrl.name, ''); //for IE
            }
            else {
                //but for other browsers you should use
                var overridctrl = document.getElementById(ctrl);
                __doPostBack(overridectrl.name, '');
            }
        }
    };
```

By looking into 'yourForm._EVENTTARGET.value' and 'yourForm._EVENTARGUMENT.value' I could see those values were not being set. By using 'document.getelementId' and passing the 'control.name' sets those values and enables the '__dopostpack' to invoke the serverside event.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `this` keyword instead. In the context of your input's `onkeypress` event, `this` will refer to the input object. Therefore, `this.id` will be sufficient. Example below:

```
<input id="tbSearch" runat="server"
                  class="sb_input" type="text"
                  autocomplete="off"  
                  onkeypress="return OverridePostBackOnEnter(event, this.id);" />
```

**EDIT**

Totally misread your post. Correct answer below:

```
<input id="tbSearch" runat="server"
   class="sb_input" type="text"
   autocomplete="off"  
 onkeypress="return OverridePostBackOnEnter(event, '<%#ImageButton3.ClientID%>');" />
```

Comment: would that not pass the id of the input control? i need the clientid of the ImageButton control

Comment: You're correct. It appears that both @JamesJohnson and I misread your post.

Comment: Yep tried that one my alert shows the text <%= ImageButton3.ClientID %> not the clientid as you would expect.

Comment: @NeilHodges, try `<%# ImageButton3.ClientID %>` instead.

Comment: hmm seem to get a javascript error with that one - Error: illegal XML character, dont think it likes the <%# part

Answer (score 1):

Just use `this.id`:

```
OverridePostBackOnEnter(event, this.id);
```

You could also change the method and just pass in the element itself:

```
OverridePostBackOnEnter(event, this);
```

**EDIT**

To pass in the ClientID of the ImageButton, try something like this:

```
OverridePostBackOnEnter(event, '<%= ImageButton3.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: would that not pass the id of the input control? i need the clientid of the ImageButton control

Comment: Yep tried that one my alert shows the text <%= ImageButton3.ClientID %> not the clientid as you would expect.

Comment: I think html inputs have a tough time interpretting inline code. Can you use a `TextBox` control instead?

Comment: unfortunatley no, the code has already been written. The reason im doing this is further up the page im disabling all enter keypress on all input textboxs, then setting each input to override that by passing 2 params to a override function, this is generic, it accepts the clientid and the argument i.e. onclick, which inturn uses the __dopostback to invoke the serverside event.

Comment: @NeilHodges, if I provided a code-behind solution, would you be able to use that?

Comment: unfortunatley no again, i was hoping to get away with it being a javascript function, thus just passing the id and the event of the control i want to invoke a postback on to the function and let the __dopostback handle the server side event. That way i can use that generic function anywhere in the site, on any control by just passing 2 params to that function.

Answer (score 0):

it's hacky, but this would work....

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/butt_searchoff.png"
    class="sb_search" ToolTip="Search the Database" AlternateText="Search" OnClick="ImageButton3_Click" OnClientClick="SetExpandedCount()"/>

    <input id="tbSearch" runat="server" class="sb_input" type="text" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return OverridePostBackOnEnter(event, '<asp:Literal ID="otherControlsClientIDHolder" runat="server" />');" />
```

Then on the server side set the text property of the literal to the client id of the image button....

```
otherControlsClientIDHolder.Text = ImageButton3.ClientID;
```

And James Hill's answer above is better than mine.  It is functionally the same thing, but his is cleaner.  +1 to James Hill's answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to add the attribute server side on page load.

```
tbSearch.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return OverridePostBackOnEnter(event, '" + ImageButton3.ClientID + "');");
```